# Facebook iOS SDK - Game Request

Tags: ios, request

I implemented the game request web view popup the following way:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary new];

// Filter and only show targeted friends
if (member.facebookId) {
    if ([member.facebookId length] > 0) {
        NSString *selectIDsStr = member.facebookId;
        params[@"to"] = selectIDsStr;
        params[@"action_type"] = @"turn";
    }
}

if (!message)
    message = facebookHelper_gameRequestMessageDefault;

// Display the requests dialog
[FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                              message:message
                                                title:facebookHelper_gameRequestTitle
                                           parameters:params
                                              handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                                                  [self handleRequest:successBlock member:member cancelBlock:cancelBlock resultURL:resultURL result:result errorBlock:errorBlock error:error];
                                              }
                                          friendCache:nil];
```

Everything works fine in the code. I receive the request id from Facebook with the Facebook user id of the invited user.

My issue is that a lot of the users (around 50%) don't receive the Facebook notification (even when i receive the request id from FB). Sometimes, when the user sends the game request a second time, the invited user receives the notification. Sometimes it does not. It seems really random.

What could be the issue?